# When is hibernate second level cache updated?

Tags: database, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

I have Parent-Child relationship.

The relationship is such that **Parent** can have a set of child and a **Child** can have of set parents.

At one point, a child **C1** from parent **P1** is removed and is assigned to another parent **P2**.

What I was doing was :

```
Parent p1 = myDao.getParent(p1_oid);
Child c1 = p1.getChild(child_oid);
p1.removeChild(c1);
Parent p2 = myDao.getParent(p2_oid);
p2.addChild(c1);

myDao.merge(p1);
myDao.merge(p2);
```

This piece of code was updating my database table properly. But in my code when I am retrieving the set of **child** using **myDao.getAllChild()** the parent for **C1** is still **P1** not **P2**.

**timeToLiveSeconds** for the cache region is **600** and I can see that exactly after 10 mins(600 seconds) if i retrieve the set of child, the parent is updated properly, i.e., parent of **c1** is now **p2**.

My question here is why was the cache not updated when I did the merge()?

I changed my above piece of code a bit to :

```
Parent p1 = myDao.getParent(p1_oid);
Child c1 = p1.getChild(child_oid);
p1.removeChild(c1);

Parent p2 = myDao.getParent(p2_oid);

 //added this line.
c1.addParent(p2);

p2.addChild(c1);

myDao.merge(p1);
myDao.merge(p2);
```

Now when I am doing myDao.getAllChild() I am able to get updated set of child.(i.e., with parent of **C1** as **P2**)

Can some one tell me what is happening here?

Comment: What cache provider are you using? What cache concurrency strategy do these entities use?

Comment: i am using ehcache and using read-write strategy